# How to apply two filters to one list using stream api

Tags: java, java-8

I would like to add a second filter to  a list, I want to exclude the empty String beside distinct the duplicate from List of Strings.

Here is what I tried, using the stream API:

This will distinct the result but not the empty

```
List<User> users = userService.getUsers(form.getId());
    List<String> positionNames = users.stream().map(User::getTitle).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can I combine them together?

Comment: `.distinct().filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())`?

Comment: I don't fully understand. Do you want empty strings to not be present in the result?

Comment: I find it odd that you know the word "filter" but do not know of the method named `filter`. Perhaps you would benefit from another read-through of the documentation on Streams.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `filter` to keep non-empty strings only:

```
List<String> positionNames = users.stream()
    .map(User::getTitle)
    .distinct()
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you don't care about order, collecting to a `Set` would have the same effect as using `distinct()`:

```
Set<String> positionNames = users.stream()
    .map(User::getTitle)
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

**EDIT:** In case there are `null` titles for some users, you might also want to filter them out:

```
Set<String> positionNames = users.stream()
    .map(User::getTitle)
    .filter(s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Or calling `filter` twice:

```
Set<String> positionNames = users.stream()
    .map(User::getTitle)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: you are always give me surprise, why didn't accept yours?

Comment: What if the string s is null?

Comment: @Samarland if the string is null, you need to add another filter, or change the condition to `s != null && !s.isEmpty()`. But that wasn't part of the question.

Comment: It just came to my mind when I applied your answer. I did know that I can use the filter but was missing part on how to combine two filters together, thank you very much. your answer helped a lot!

Comment: @Samarland glad it was of help, I will edit the answer later with your suggestion

Comment: @holi-java his answer didn't come the first, I had to try the other answer, but when I came back to ask found his answer better :)  thank you again @@FedericoPeraltaSchaffner

Comment: @Samarland Hi, thanks for you feedback. I can understand it now.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner well you honestly deserver them :) congrats!

Comment: Federico Peralta Schaffner sounds like you're the expert here, I should keep tagging you on my question!

Comment: @Samarland Added example to handle null values in the stream

Comment: @ Federico Peralta Schaffner what's the difference between Objects::nonNull and s != null ?

Comment: @Samarland Tha lambda expression `s -> s != null` and the method reference `Objects::nonNull` are equivalent

Answer (score 3):

`users.stream().map(User::getTitle).distinct().filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: This will only leave empty strings. He wants to remove the empty strings.